# ASP.NET trying to compile commented lines of code. Why?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have code like this on some aspx page in my Web Application:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Laber1" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button1" onclick="btn1_Click" />
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<!--
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAjaxToolkit" runat="server" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAjaxToolkit" /> 
-->
</asp:Content>
```

When I compile the project and go to this page in the browser, I get this exception:

```
[InvalidOperationException: На страницу можно добавить только один экземпляр ScriptManager.]
```

(translate: "There only one instance of ScriptManager allowed on this page").

Why do I get this message if second script manager (ToolkitScriptManager) is located in comments?

I am using ASP.NET 4 and ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit.

P.S: Sorry for my english.

Comment: If you remove the comments does it compile? i.e. is there another ScriptManager somewhere else?

Comment: It works if you (temporarily) delete the commented lines?

Comment: If i remove commented block it is working. As AVD and Jon Skeet said below i need to use server-side comments <%-- --%>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've used *HTML* comments, but the markup engine doesn't care about that - it'll still try to generate the content of that HTML comment. After all, you might want something like a timestamp in a comment.

You want a [server-side comment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/09/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Using-Server-Side-Comments-with-ASP.NET-2.0-.aspx), like this;

```
<%--
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAjaxToolkit" runat="server" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
                      TargetControlID="txtAjaxToolkit" /> 
--%>
```

It's all a matter of working out what's going to figure out that something is a comment - the HTML `<!-- comment -->` is aimed at a browser; the `<%-- comment --%> is aimed at the ASPX processor.

Answer (score 7):

Use server side [comment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/09/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Using-Server-Side-Comments-with-ASP.NET-2.0-.aspx) syntax.

```
<%---
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAjaxToolkit" runat="server" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAjaxToolkit" />
---%>
```